# Where and how does ctime allocate memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, ctime

I'm using [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/) function to get a readable representation of `time_t` variable. `ctime` is declared as follows:

```
char *ctime (const time_t *timer);
```

and you can see that it returns a pointer to the resulting char array without any char pointer passed in arguments. Thus I'm wondering where does `ctime` allocate char buffer and who will destroy it and isn't allocating memory inside function (except various `malloc`'s, of course) considered to be a mess.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the link you quote:

> The array which holds this string is **statically allocated** and shared by both the ctime and asctime functions. Each time either one of these functions is called the content of this array is overwritten

That array lasts as long as the program does, it must not be freed by anyone.

POSIX 2008 has a [`ctime_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/ctime_r.html) function that is re-entrant (you pass in your buffer), but it is not standard in C or C++.

Comment: And if you don't like this behavior, your platform probably has `ctime_r`.

Comment: What a shame... I didn't think i can be _so attentive_. Sorry for silly question and thanks =)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Do'h! I had always been annoyed at that statically allocated thing but never thought about checking whether reentrant versions existed.